# Get created and modified date after editing response from google forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

```
function assignEditUrls() {
    var form = FormApp.openById('Your form key goes here');
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Your responses Google Sheet name goes here - The tab name, not the file name');
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var urlCol = Column number where URLs get entered goes here;
    var responses = form.getResponses();
    var timestamps = [],
        urls = [],
        resultUrls = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
        timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
        urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
    }
    for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
        resultUrls.push([data[j][0] ? urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))] : '']);
    }
    sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);
}
```

I am currently using this code which allows me to update the record which is generating a edit link to edit that respective record. But the challenge is that it also changes the timestamp.

Question is

How can we amend this code so i can get created and last modified date and time for the particular record in the google sheet?

Any help much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: If you want to get data from your linked sheet I would use the onFormSubmit trigger for the spreadsheet and just take it from the namedValues or the values right out of the event object.  Looking for it on the spreadsheet is a bad idea.

Comment: Could you share a sample spreadsheet and the desired output?

Comment: Hi,

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ljSWdA62FAH-XERv8Uew5KmR5zu-jBnRbtkgzgHe928/edit#gid=0

how the sheet works:

1) When I enter data through google form, it gets filled in sheet 1.

2) After running the script it provides me the link 'Column H' to edit that record.

Now my challenge is everytime i update any row through this link('Column H' the timestamp in 'Column A' changes.

I want created and modified timestamp differently. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HarshitDesai - Access denied, Kindly make your spreadsheet public.

Comment: @NikkoJ. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ljSWdA62FAH-XERv8Uew5KmR5zu-jBnRbtkgzgHe928/edit?usp=sharing  

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an onFormSubmit Trigger to save the created date of your rows whenever a new record is added. By using this method, we can easily store the **Created Date** and the **Modified Date** (Timestamp) which you can use for other operations.

**Example:**

Here I updated the email of Test Data 1:

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
function assignEditUrls() {
    var form = FormApp.openById('Enter form id here');
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var urlCol = 9;
    var responses = form.getResponses();
    var urls = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
      urls.push([responses[i].getEditResponseUrl()]);
    }
    sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, urls.length).setValues(urls);
}


function triggerTest(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var createdDateCol = 8;
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  sheet.getRange(1, createdDateCol, 1, 1).setValue("Created Date"); // Add created date header
  var cdRange = sheet.getRange(row, createdDateCol, 1, 1);
  if(cdRange.getValue() == ''){ // this indicates that the record is new
     cdRange.setValue(e.namedValues['Timestamp'])
  }
}
```

### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)